# How to optimize for REST heavy code in SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

In my sharepoint 2013 environment, I am using REST a lot, but I use techniques like storing in client side cache, and lazy loading. But I was wondering if there was anything more I can do.

In general, does SharePoint do any server side caching for REST calls? Note: I'm not talking about content search webparts, but just regular jquery ajax with REST. Besides client side caching, is there a way to make SharePoint cache REST call results server side?

Thanks